Dask Can't synchronously read data shared on NFS
Running Dask Scheduler on system A and workers on system A and B. NFS volume from system A is shared on the network through NFS with system B, and contains the data files. This folder has a symbolic link to my home directory due to path issues.
When running with workers from system B I get the following error:
OSError: [Errno 5] Can't synchronously read data (file read failed: time = Tue Apr 30 18:12:40 2024
, filename = '/home/steffan/raw_sarez2017_desc/S1_20170511_ALL_F2.grd', file descriptor = 18, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x757e7079f720, total read size = 40136, bytes this sub-read = 40136, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 0)

When only working with system A I get no errors. Is there a reason why Dask is throwing synchronous IO errors when using workers from a different system on the same network?

Hi there is no reason Dask would throws such error, it probably comes from your NFS share, on a lower lever. NFS can often be a bottleneck or present performance issues.

can you read files from the NFS share outside of Dask?
